# What is the status of a Stripe subscription AFTER a trial is over?

Tags: stripe-payments

When a user registers, I'm creating a subscription with:

```
    const stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: req.body.stripeCustomerId,
        items: [{
            price: process.env['STRIPE_PRICE_ID']
        }],
        trial_period_days: 7
    })
```

This goes ahead and creates a subscription with a status of `trialing`. What happens when the trial expires? Assuming the person does not have a payment method attached, I don't think it'll be `active`, will it? So then what status will the subscription have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will become `active`. You can confirm this yourself in test mode using `trial_end={A_FEW_MINUTES_FROM_NOW}`. Assuming the associated Price is for a non-zero amount, a draft invoice will be create as happens with normal billing cycle renewals, but that invoice will remain open unless you set up a Payment Method to use or explicitly `/pay` it.

Comment: Hmmmm.... but I need to know if they've paid or not.

Comment: You can inspect the `latest_invoice` on the subscription or listen for `invoice.paid` events or list all invoice for a given `subscription` using the API. There are several ways to accomplish what you're looking for, but none change the answer to your actual question.